# PHP Generate Signature With PKCS8 Private Key for API

Tags: php, openssl, pkcs#8

I'm totally new in encrypting data using these private and public key. Many tutorials teach to generate and sign the data, but missing information about what to do with these keys actually.

What to do after I generate my public key and PKCS8 private key with OpenSSL?

Should I give the public key manually to the person who responsible for the corresponding request server? Or somehow there's specific or special way to send or included it using script in the API request?

Then is this code enough to sign data as signature if the .pem private key encoded with PKCS8?

```
$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private($path_to_key);
$data = 'Text to sign';
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key);
openssl_free_key($private_key);
```

Comment: @KenLee Wait, you edited.

Comment: @KenLee Oh, I understand. Doesn't use this often, I will wait for answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, some basic but essential information:

Public key cryptography is a method of encrypting or signing data with two different keys and making one of the keys, the public key, available for anyone to use.

The other key is known as the private key. Data `encrypted with the public key` can only be `decrypted with the private key`.

Note: The private key represents your identity. Anyone who knows it can use it to impersonate you. It should never be shared with anyone that you do not trust to act in your place as if they were you.

`For digital signature`, the private key is uniquely associated with the owner and is not made public. This key is used to compute a digital signature that may be `verified` using the corresponding public key.

**A typical example**: Mary signs a message—"Hello John!"—by appending a signature computed from the message and her private key. John receives both the message and signature. He uses Mary's public key to verify the authenticity of the signed message.

Now for the coding (for encryption first)

(OPTION ONE)

For PHP generation of PKCS8 public / private keys, you may use the phpseclib PHP library. See [Official Site](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/intro.html)

After downloading and decompressing the library, you may then use the following PHP code to generate both the private key and public key (make sure you have both the necessary files in `Crypt` and `Math` directories:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8);

extract($rsa->createKey());

echo "Private Key (PKCS8) :<br><br>";
echo $privatekey . "<br><br>";


echo "Public Key (PKCS8) :<br><br>";
echo $publickey;
echo "<br><br>";


/// Now try to encrypt and decrypt


$rsa->loadKey($publickey); // public key

$plaintext = 'Stack Overflow';

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS8);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);

/// Finished encryption, now decrypt

$rsa->loadKey($privatekey); // private key
$finaltext= $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);

echo "String decrypt : " . $finaltext;
```

(OPTION TWO)

On the other hand, if you are not using the phpseclib PHP library, you may use the following standard openssl approach

```
<?php 
$config = [ 
    "private_key_bits" => 2048, 
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA, 
]; 
  
$keypair = openssl_pkey_new($config); 
  
openssl_pkey_export($keypair, $private_key); 
  
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($keypair); 
$public_key = $public_key["key"]; 
  
echo "Private key: " . $private_key . "<br><br>"; 
echo "Public key: " . $public_key . "<br><br>"; 

echo "<br><br>";


/// Now try to encrypt and decrypt

$data = "Stack Overflow";

openssl_public_encrypt($data,$crypttext,$public_key);

echo "Encrypted Data : <br><br>";
echo $crypttext;
echo "<br><br>";


/// Finished encryption, now decrypt

openssl_private_decrypt ($crypttext,$finaltext,$private_key);

echo "String decrypt : ". $finaltext;


?>
```

Both of the above two codes will display `String decrypt : Stack Overflow` as the last sentence

Now, coding (for digital signature)

if you would like to use the `sign the data with PKCS8 Private Key`:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//$rsa->setPassword('password');


$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8);

extract($rsa->createKey());

/*
echo "Private Key (PKCS8) :<br><br>";
echo $privatekey . "<br><br>";


echo "Public Key (PKCS8) :<br><br>";
echo $publickey;
echo "<br><br>";
*/


$rsa->loadKey($privatekey); // private key

$plaintext = 'Stack Overflow';

$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS8);
$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);

echo "Signature is :<br><br>";
echo $signature;
echo "<br><br>";

$rsa->loadKey($publickey); // public key
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
?>
```

or , use standard openssl approach

```
<?php
$config = [ 
    "private_key_bits" => 2048, 
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA, 
]; 
  
$keypair = openssl_pkey_new($config); 
  
openssl_pkey_export($keypair, $private_key); 
  
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_details($keypair); 
$public_key = $public_key["key"]; 
  
echo "Private key: " . $private_key . "<br><br>"; 
echo "Public key: " . $public_key . "<br><br>"; 

echo "<br><br>";


$data = "Stack Overflow";

openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key);
openssl_free_key($private_key);


// state whether signature is okay or not

$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "verified";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "unverified";
} else {
   echo "error: ".openssl_error_string();
}
// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($public_key);
?>
```

Both the above will display `verified` (of course)

For your question on "specific or special way to send or included it using script in the API request", actually you may use your own methods to distribute the public key. In some cases the user will simply send the data with the signature thru email (see Mary and John example above). On the other hand,a web system administrator usually will allow a logged-in user to download the public key by clicking a URL.